# IE11 Redirecting to Microsoft Edge on launch

Tags: internet-explorer

After October 2023, it's not an option to use IE11 on Windows anymore. Is there any workaround to keep using the browser other than the known VB script?

Comment: Don't use IE. For those sites that require it, use Edge's provided compatibility mode. But serious, DON'T USE IE. There's a good reason it is dead, and it should have died a long time before it actually did.

Comment: What is your requirement to use IE11 that Internet Explorer mode in Edge cannot solve?